# best way to deserialize xml in c#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have following xml:

```
<return_obj from_call_to="categories">
  <categories>
    <category>
      <value>12341234</value>
      <label>First</label>
    </category>
    <category>
      <value>242234234</value>
      <label>Another</label>
    </category>
  </categories>
</return_obj>
```

so marked up an object to serialize this into

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "return_obj")]
public class returnobject
{
    [XmlElement]
    public category[] categories { get; set; }
}

public class category
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string value { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

and tried using this to do it

```
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (returnobject));
    var obj = (returnobject)ser.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("test.xml"));
```

However, the categories collection always some ups null.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlSerializer only looks at public fields and properties, so you have to make `categories`  public in your `returnobject` class.

Also you have to specify the name of the XML array container you want to use, in your case `categories` - this worked for me:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "return_obj")]
public class returnobject
{
    [XmlArray("categories")]
    [XmlArrayItem("category")]
    public category[] categories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that did deserialise "categories" but only loads 1 single category and both value/label are null..

Comment: @andryuha: check my edit, we must have posted at the same time

Comment: awesome, that did it...is this a common way of doing xml deserialization?

Comment: @andryuha: I would say yes, it's pretty common using the XmlSerializer this way - in general you should avoid public fields though in your classes, use properties instead (also see the camel case naming conventions for those)

Answer (score 2):

Make `categories` field public in `class returnobject`. That would help.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, XmlSerializer has to generate type information of the serialization types. This can take a while, so you might find serialization and deserialization taking several hundred milliseconds. You can get around this by running SGEN to pre-generate the serialization assemblies.

Alternatively, you can use XmlReader to read the XML and just code the serialization yourself. It's more code, but always performs well and isn't burdened with the extra assembly (generated or not).